# problema tcpdf datos uno encima de otro

Tags: php, pdf

hola estoy presentando un problema cuando se genera el pdf por medio de TCPDF y es que al final de la pagina se estan amontonando las letras
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que estoy usando

```
$pdf->Ln($margin10);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, 'Momentos Ejecución',1, 'C', $fill);
$pdf->MultiCell($w3, 7, "Fecha", 1, 'C', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'M');
$pdf->MultiCell($w3, 7, "Momentos", 1, 'C', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 7, 'M');
$pdf->MultiCell($w3, 7, 'Observaciones', 1, 'C', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 7, 'M');
$pdf->Ln();
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($trazabilidadEjecucion);
if(count($row1)>0){
      $x=0; $y=0;
      foreach ($trazabilidadEjecucion as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $col) {
          if($pdf->GetY()>170){$pdf->AddPage();}
            $pdf->MultiCell($w3, 20, validarDatos($col), 1, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true,20, 'M');
        }
        $pdf->Ln();
      }
}else{
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 10, "Sin Registros", 1, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M');
    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

Comment: en cada hoja alcanza para 8 filas

Comment: tcpdf es una librería muy potente que sirve como base a otras librerías en php para generar los reportes. Aunque se puede utilizar tcpdf directamente no lo recomiendo ya que este mismo reporte cuando debas anexarle o eliminarle algo tan sencillo como una columna por ejemplo te generará inmensos dolores de cabeza debido a que generalmente cualquier cambio mínimo realizado al reporte lo "rompe" y terminas gastando más tiempo en arreglarlo para ejecutar un cambio o mantenimiento solicitado que el tiempo que gastarías generando uno nuevo con el cambio solicitado

Comment: Tcpdf es una librería potente que funciona como base a otras librerías php que te simplifican la labor de generar los reportes. Un buen ejemplo es html2pdf que te permite prácticamente generar el reporte pdf con la estructura de html y css que ya tenías en tu sitio web, es decir, puedes utilizar la mayoría de las etiquetas por lo que para dibujar una tablar no requieres "dibujar pixel a pixel" como en tcpdf sino que utilizas thead-tbody para dibujarla. Al final te ahorrará mucho tiempo y evitará dolores de cabeza a la hora de realizar algún cambio  y generar nuevos reportes

Comment: Te dejo el link de [html2pdf](https://html2pdf.fr/es/home) y además si quieres aún simplificar más tu trabajo y optimizar tu tiempo podrías utilizar algún reporteador como por ejemplo [JasperReports + php + ireport](https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP) que genera una excelente solución para la generación de reportes. No son las únicas soluciones disponibles para el mercado pero si te garantizo que te resultará productivo utilizar cualquiera de estas dos alternativas en vez de "raw" tcpdf. Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo